# How to manage 2 DAO methods in a single transaction?

Tags: spring, transaction, service, dao

In an interview someone asked me : How do we manage 2 transactional/dao methods in a single transaction. Desired capabilities:

1. If anyone of them fails we need to rollback both methods.
2. Both of the methods can be called separately attached with a single transaction.
3. The management should be on DAO layer, not on service layer.

I think : the question relates to spring transaction management.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, transaction management should be done on service layer, not on DAO layer as that would create a lot of performance overhead (to deal with appropriate transaction isolation level and propagation at each different method). Also, the scope of a ***unit of work*** comes from the service layer instead of the data access layer: imagine performing a business process that needs to deal with 2 or more DAOs.

There is a lot of discussion in the Internet that points in that direction as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171605/understanding-spring-transactions-what-happens-when-a-transactional-method-cal), [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-49244.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/spring-transactional-annotation-best-practice).

Anyway, since it's an interview let's accept the question as is. From my point of view, you would be using the `@Transactional` annotation (or the XML configuration) in both methods and with a transaction propagation with `REQUIRED` value. That way, when any of those methods is invoked and if no previous transaction exist, a new transaction will be created:

```
@Transactional
class MyDAO {

   @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)
   public void foo() {
   }

   @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)
   public void bar() {
   }

}
```

Comment: Is it means `foo()` and `bar()` share the same transaction and if 1 fail another 1 will also rollback? Can you provide some clarification?

Comment: well, each method declares its own unit of work: tx will be committed at the end of each method and if any of them throws an exception it will be rolled-back.

Comment: so we need to add `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)`in DAO layer method for propagation and `@Transactional` on service layer, but if I put `@Transactional` on service layer only instead of putting in on DAO layer, what is difference?

Comment: `propagation = REQUIRED` is the default value for the transactional annotation propagation, so it isn't neccesary to write it.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring spring and frameworks in my answer..... just the basic idea of using function parameters. I'm sure the concept could apply within [insert framework here].

You would need to handle the commit/rollback outside of the 2 DAO methods. The 2 methods would need to take the transaction/connection as input.

psuedo code:

```
bool method1(Tran t) { /* stuff */}
bool method2(Tran t) { /* stuff */ }

callingMethod() {
     Tran t = null;
     try {
         t = new Conn().open().startTran();
         if(method1(t) && method2(t))
             t.commit();
         else
             t.rollBaack();
     }
     catch(ex) {  t.rollBack();  }
     finally {  t.closeConn();  }
}
```

Comment: 1 question : why we are passing `Tran t` as a parameter with both methods. Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: @Satish, because in the question (item #1 and #2), the DAO methods need to have the flexibility to be called independently as well as dependently.  If you commit inside method1 with a local-scope transaction then you could not roll back if something went wrong in method2 as you have already committed method1 before method2 was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that two methods should work independently also at the same time there might run in a same transaction.So we need to use Propagation-Required.
If the transaction has to run in same transaction then it will use the first transaction else a new transaction is created if invoked independently.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?